# Django - model that has a count per CHOICES Field

Tags: django, django-models, django-model-field

django 2.1, python 3.6

Let's say I have a set of things ['house_1','house_2',...] and I want to have a model that keeps a count of each item. I'd imagine that it'd look like the following.

```
class Card(models.Model):
    house_1_count = models.IntegerField(...
    house_2_count = models.IntegerField(...
    house_3_count = models.IntegerField(...
```

Is there a way to convert this model so that the items are not hard coded. Like by using a CHOICES field. The items in my list may change (slowly), but I don't want to have to create a field in the model every time it happens.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, I don't think it would be wise to store the `count` of houses in a model. If you want to get count, then simply do it like this using **[count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count)**:

```
House.objects.filter(house_type=1).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a choice field in your model rather than storing each count.
Update you `card` model:

```
class Card(models.Model):
    house = models.IntegerField(choices=list(zip(range(1, 4), range(1, 4))), max_length=1)
```

To count Card with particular type house use `count()`:

```
Card.objects.filter(house=1).count()
```